# Engine smooth after techron then rough again

Tags: engine, fuel-additives

I used techron additive. After a gas tankful, the engine is smooth and powerful as new.

However after another tankful of normal gas the engine is rough and sluggish again. Why is this happening?

What can I do to make the effects lasting?

Comment: You are adding the fuel additive to the gas, not going to a Chevron station and using their gas? If so, are you continuing to utilize the same gas/gas station for the fuel up?

Comment: I use mostly chevron. So it was Chevron 98 Premium + Techron additive, then Shell VPower then it was smooth till 1/4 to Empty. Then Chevron 98 Premium again then it feels rough already.

Comment: What is the year/make/model/mileage of your vehicle?

Comment: 2004/mazda/3/118,000 km/73,000 miles

Comment: What engine does it have (sorry, forgot to ask)?

Comment: 1.6L Petrol Z6 engine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Z_engine